# How can I set user and password in Java for JAAS?

Tags: java, authentication, jaas

I wouldn't like to use the several JAAS.conf files in order to authenticate with different servers. Therefore I am looking for a solution to provide user and password during runtime programmatically. - Without using JAAS.conf

Comment: That's what the JAAS callbacks are for.

Comment: I thought callbacks are for user interaction. But this is not what I want.

Comment: No. The callbacks are for the application to provide information to the login module. They can be interactive, but there's nothing that says they have to be. In a webapp, for example, they just supply the values of `j_username/j_password` that the user has already entered on a form and posted to the webapp: no interactivity there.